# Socket is only catching outgoing packets, not incoming ones

Tags: c#, sockets, networking

I have based a packet sniffer on [this (frequently cited) sample project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17031/A-Network-Sniffer-in-C). After implementing the HTTP packets I have noticed that the only HTTP packets I'm picking up are requests, I'm not receiving any responses.

I have looked at many different sources but since the code used is very often the same I am inclined to think it might be local to myself.

When I look at my logs I see that every packet has my local IP as `SourceIP`, both for HTTP packets as well as packets that arrive at other ports.

I have provided a working sample [here](https://gist.github.com/Vannevelj/9174915) which you can copy-paste into LINQPad and should demonstrate the problem (add the `System.Net` and `System.Net.Socket` assemblies). Don't forget to execute LINQPad as administrator to have access to the socket.

This results in hundreds/thousands of entries in the 192.168.0 range with a total of 3 exceptions of IP addresses that refer to my hosting provider (checked using `nslookup`).

```
private readonly byte[] _data = new byte[4096];   
private Socket _mainSocket;

public void Capture()
{
    _mainSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
    _mainSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(GetLocalIP(), 0));

    var byTrue = new byte[] {1, 0, 0, 0};
    var byOut = new byte[] {1, 0, 0, 0};

    _mainSocket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, byTrue, byOut); 

    _mainSocket.EnableBroadcast = true;
    _mainSocket.BeginReceive(_data, 0, _data.Length, SocketFlags.None, OnReceive, null);
}

private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    SocketError error;
    var received = _mainSocket.EndReceive(ar, out error);
    Parse(_data, received);
    _mainSocket.BeginReceive(_data, 0, _data.Length, SocketFlags.None, OnReceive, null);
}

private void Parse(byte[] data, int size)
{
     var packet = new IPHeader(data, size);
     Console.WriteLine (packet.SourceIP.ToString());
}
```

- Windows 8.1
- <del>Killer e2200 Gigabit Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.30) - Latest version of driver</del>

  - Installed a standalone network card yesterday, it didn't change anything.

[A post](http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/sniff-outgoing-packets-58370.aspx)'s description that came closest to my problem has as solution the working code that I already have.

Why am I only able to trace outbound packets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As both @Saibal and @Saverio have mentioned: the firewall is the issue. As a temporary solution for now I'm disabling the firewall when the packettracer starts and enabling it back when it stops (not taking an unexpected exit in account).

If you end up here with the same problem then your first result for "disable firewall C#" might be [this blogpost](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/securitytools/archive/2009/08/21/automating-windows-firewall-settings-with-c.aspx). This did not work in my case and instead threw a `NotImplementedException`. I'm guessing that this is only possibly on Windows XP as [this MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365330%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) indicates.

Luckily there are alternatives for Vista and upwards (only tested on Windows 8.1 but [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff956124%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is supposedly the successor and mentions this).

My code to disable/enable the firewall:

```
private static readonly Type policyType = 
                          Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2");
private static readonly INetFwPolicy2 firewall = 
                         (INetFwPolicy2) Activator.CreateInstance(policyType);

private void DisableFirewall()
{
    var firewallEnabled = firewall.get_FirewallEnabled(
                              NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE2_.NET_FW_PROFILE2_PRIVATE);
    if (firewallEnabled)
    {
          firewall.set_FirewallEnabled(
                       NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE2_.NET_FW_PROFILE2_PRIVATE, false);
    }
}
```

An alternative way of writing this is

```
firewall.FirewallEnabled[NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE2_.NET_FW_PROFILE2_PRIVATE] = false;
```

Sadly, MSDN offers only [code samples in C / C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd339606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but you can still take away the gist of it.

Keep in mind that you have to add the *Interop.NetFwTypeLib* library to your project. You can find it at *C:\Windows\SysWOW64\FirewallAPI.dll* or the 32bit equivalent.

This is very rudimentary however. In a later stage (this post will get updated whenever I do) I will look into simply adding the program to the firewall's list of exceptions but right now this will have to suffice.

Answer (score 5):

Did you try looking into your OS / Standalone / Router firewall?
It is often overlooked, but Firewalls have different rules for incoming and outgoing connections and that might be the cause of your issues.

Comment: [Looks like you were right after all](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21972478/socket-is-only-catching-outgoing-packets-not-incoming-ones#comment33438735_22051702). It never occurred to me to simply turn it off and see what happens, I was just looking at settings.

Comment: I am glad I was of help :)

Answer (score 1):

Check the address returned by your GetLocalIP(). You may be receiving a loopback ip, in which case you cannot capture packets coming in. Similar issue discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753743/socket-receiveall).

Comment: The IP returned is `192.168.0.199`.

Comment: Ahh!!! Its the firewall. Turning off the firewall makes it work okay. Need to figure out the configuration required by the firewall to get things to work. For a quick test disable firewall. At least works for me:)

Comment: Indeed it seems to work here as well. When I add LINQPad to the list of allowed programs for incoming connections, it's working with the firewall enabled as well. This is very good progress.