# How to extract an IPv4 address from a Packet?

Tags: c#, ip, packet

I have this `byte[]` that represent `IPv4 packet`:

```
byte[] arr = { 0, 48, 136, 21, 69, 131, 0, 24, 231, 253, 174, 161, 8, 0, 69, 0, 0, 52, 2, 31, 64, 0, 128, 6, 230, 22, 212, 25, 99, 74, 202, 177, 16, 121, 194, 156, 0, 119, 160, 128, 75, 200, 249, 141, 210, 78, 80, 24, 64, 252, 130, 182, 0, 0, 65, 82, 84, 73, 67, 76, 69, 32, 51, 52, 13, 10 };
```

And i want to calculate the `IPV4 address`

Comment: Take a look here, this may help you? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header

Comment: Which `IPv4 address` do you want?

Comment: I show it but didn't understand this and how to calculate my ip address

Comment: To start with, that doesn´t look like an IP-Packet to me

Comment: I want the source and the destination

Comment: Again, this is not an IP packet. If i didn´t make any stupid errors, the source address would be 8.0.69.0, the destination 0.52.2.31, and the total length 34837 byte. Which is not valid / not true.

Comment: I am using PcapDotNet DLLs and i took ik after parse this packet into byte[]: byte[] arr = packet.Buffer, after compare this packet with Wireshark ican see that this is different but how ?

Comment: Without seeing your capturing code: No idea. But the error will be there

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple parser to examine your byte array:

```
void Main()
{
    byte[] arr = { 0, 48, 136, 21, 69, 131, 0, 24, 231, 253, 174, 161, 8, 0, 69, 0, 0, 52, 2, 31, 64, 0, 128, 6, 230, 22, 212, 25, 99, 74, 202, 177, 16, 121, 194, 156, 0, 119, 160, 128, 75, 200, 249, 141, 210, 78, 80, 24, 64, 252, 130, 182, 0, 0, 65, 82, 84, 73, 67, 76, 69, 32, 51, 52, 13, 10 };
    var stream = new MemoryStream(arr, 0, arr.Length);
    var reader = new BinaryReader(stream);

    Print("Version and header length", reader.ReadByte());
    Print("Diff services", reader.ReadByte());

    Print("Total length", IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(reader.ReadInt16())); 
    Print("ID", IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(reader.ReadInt16()));
    Print("Flags and offset", IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(reader.ReadInt16()));

    Print("TTL", reader.ReadByte());
    Print("Protocol", reader.ReadByte());
    Print("Checksum", reader.ReadInt16());

    Print("Source IP", new IPAddress((int) reader.ReadInt32()));
    Print("Destination IP", new IPAddress((int) reader.ReadInt32()));
}
```

This produces this output:

```
Version and header length = 0
Diff services = 48
Total length = -30699
ID = 17795
Flags and offset = 24
TTL = 231
Protocol = 253
Checksum = -24146
Source IP = 8.0.69.0
Destination IP = 0.52.2.31
```

This doesn't seem very right (negative length/checksum? + the protocol should return '6' for TCP or '8' for UDP). You might want to verify your data is correct first.

I wrote this up with code from [a tiny project of mine](https://github.com/Vannevelj/NetworkInspector/blob/master/NetworkInspector/Models/Headers/Network/IPHeader.cs) which might help you with future issues. Definitely look at the packet layout on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header), you'll need it with DNS/UDP as well.

Comment: What this project doing ?

Comment: @user3271698: it's a tiny, buggy, packet sniffer. It reads the IP, TCP/UDP and DNS/HTTP header from outgoing packets (incoming ones not so much, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21972478/socket-is-only-catching-outgoing-packets-not-incoming-ones)).

Comment: Is it possible to replace an IPv4 address with IPv6 address ?

Comment: You can view the IP version in the first 4 bit of the header, both in IPv4 and IPv6 as you can see [here](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:IPv6_header_rv1.svg). Read the first 4 bit and perform additional parsing based on that result. It's just a matter of calling `readX()` on your stream, really.

Comment: Can i have code example ? (i am a new developer...)

Comment: @user3271698: so am I. Make an attempt yourself and you'll learn how things work, soon enough you'll be able to answer these things yourself.

Comment: OK i have all the packet: 0030881545830018e7fdaea1080045000034021f40008006e616d419634acab11079c29c0077a0804bc8f98dd24e501840fc82b6000041525449434c452033340d0a and my ipv4 address is d419634a, what next ?

Comment: Please make an attempt at writing the code yourself. I gave you a full example of how to do it with IPv4 and told you how to change it to account for IPv6, that should be enough.