# Need help to convert

Tags: c#, c++

Hi i have tried to convert the c++ code below to c# but i don seem to get it right.
I got this below in .h header file

```
public: 
unsigned char inquiry_data[256];
```

Then the .cpp file

```
sa = (PSCSI_ADDRESS)&inquiry_data[0];
```

When i Go Definition of the (`PSCSI_ADDRESS`) i got this below:

```
typedef struct _SCSI_ADDRESS {
    ULONG Length;
    UCHAR PortNumber;
    UCHAR PathId;
    UCHAR TargetId;
    UCHAR Lun;

} SCSI_ADDRESS, *PSCSI_ADDRESS;
```

---

The below are what i have tried to convert to C#

```
 public byte[] inquiry_data = new byte[256];

 public class SCSI_ADDRESS
{   
    public ulong Length;
    public byte PortNumber;
    public byte PathId;
    public byte TargetId;
    public byte Lun;
}
 sa = (SCSI_ADDRESS)inquiry_data[0];
```

However, i keep getting errors at the line `(SCSI_ADDRESS)inquiry_data[0];` with error `Cannot convert type 'byte' to 'project1.Class.SCSI_ADDRESS'`

Could you please advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a start, that C++ code is relying on *undefined behaviour*.  You cannot cast arbitrary sections of memory to complex types and then attempt to access them.

C# does not allow arbitrary casts like that.  If you are interested in turning raw bytes into data, you want to look into [C# serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx).

Comment: `char` arrays are explicitly allowed to alias other types though, so depending on the context, it seems like it could be legal (although of course, a straightforward port to C# is impossible)

Comment: It's not undefined behaivour. It's implementation-defined.

Comment: It seems to be harder than what i think. Why does it need to have serialization? Isn't there be a more simple way to convert that code?

Comment: @jalf: `T x; char *p = (char *)&x;` is fine.  But not vice versa (think about alignment issues, for a start).

Comment: @Oli: like I said, it depends on the context. Assuming you manually ensure alignment, and that a valid object actually exists at the address, it is legal. We can't say for sure from the OP's code that it is legal, but complex objects *can* be stored into a `char` array (and obviously, read back out), the standard explicitly ensures that.

Comment: @jalf: No, the OP's code (as presented) is never valid.  He starts with a `char` array, and then tries to interpret it as a `T`.  AFAIK, this is never allowed.

Comment: @belinq: The pointer cast is indeed implementation-defined (or undefined, if there are alignment issues).  But any attempt to dereference `sa` is undefined.  (To be fair, I'm basing this on the C99 standard, I would assume that this holds for C++ equivalently, but I'm checking now...)

Comment: @ybungalobill: The pointer cast is indeed implementation-defined (or undefined, if there are alignment issues). But any attempt to dereference `sa` is undefined. (To be fair, I'm basing this on the C99 standard, I would assume that this holds for C++ equivalently, but I'm checking now...)

Comment: @Oli, **it is not undefined behaivor**, the exact result is implementation-defined. Also the standard permits to serialize PODs into a char array of sizeof(yourType) and read them back. This is what the code in question does.

Comment: @Oli: C++98 [basic.types]: "For any complete POD object type T, whether or not the object holds a valid value of type T, the underlying
bytes (1.7) making up the object can be copied into an array of char or unsigned char.36) If the content
of the array of char or unsigned char is copied back into the object, the object shall subsequently
hold its original value."

Comment: @ybungalobill: Yes, but that's not what the OP is doing.  He/she is literally just *reinterpreting* some arbitrary memory, i.e. `char c[sizeof(T)]; T *p = (T*)c;`.  Your quote is alluding to something like `T x; char c[sizeof(T)]; memcpy(&x, c, sizeof(T));`, I think (i.e. there's a notion of explicit copying).

Comment: @Oli: my quote explicitly permits the both directions independently of the validity of the values.

Comment: @ybungalobill: I really don't think it does.  As in, I really don't think it says it says *anything* about `char c[sizeof(T)]; T *p = (T*)c; *p...`.  In the C99 spec, I believe this is explicitly disallowed by 6.5/7.  I haven't yet found an equivalent in C++, so perhaps the languages differ in this respect.

Comment: @ybungalobill: the quoted part of the standard allows you to *copy* the bytes themselves to a char array and *copy* them back.  The pointer to the UDT might require alignment to a 4-byte boundary, for example.  In that case, directly *casting* from 1-byte aligned char pointer to the UDT pointer will cause alignment and "truncate" the first 0 to 3 bytes of the structure.  Note that this is totally different the other way around (casting from `UDT*` to `char*`) because all 4-byte aligned pointers are also 1-byte aligned.  The posted code exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: @André, @ybungalobill: Not only that, but even if the alignment *is* ok, there's also the issue of aliasing.

Answer (score 1):

C# cannot do data cast as C++ does. While fixed typed, C++ isn't actually strong typed -- you can cast whatever you want to whatever you need.

Now, with C#, things are more complicated, because C# struggles not to enable the user to do unsafe stuff. What are you trying to do is getting a bytestream and say to the compiler, "treat it as a `SCSI_ADDRESS`.

To do this is C# you can either use serialization or unsafe sections. A quick and dirty (very dirty) way of doing this is described [here](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3897) in short.

Comment: I used the `ByteArrayToObject` function from your example. And the code here object a = ByteArrayToObject(inquiry_data);
            sa = (SCSI_ADDRESS)a; It seems to be no error but is this good to go?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an I gave answer to a similar question.

[Object to Network serialization - with an existing protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655159/object-to-network-serialization-with-an-existing-protocol)

And a link to an article I did years ago on the options

http://taylorza.blogspot.com/2010/04/archive-structure-from-binary-data.html

And this one for doing the reverse

http://taylorza.blogspot.com/2010/04/archive-binary-data-from-structure.html

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do is not possible in C#. The first issue is a typing issue. The compiler will not allow you to make a cast that it cannot verify as being valid.  This is for type safety.

Even if we ignore the complier's role you get into an issue with how that data is represented in memory. Since C# is managed language how data exists in memory is not under your control.  Unlike in C++ a struct will not take up exactly the memory that is allocated to it.  There is some inherent overhead of memory space for the object itself.  So from the very beginning you are misaligned and your information would not converted in the way you expect.

[Jon Skeet recently had a blog post about the size of objects](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/04/05/of-memory-and-strings.aspx).  Although this isn't exactly what you are trying to do it illustrates a couple fundamental flaws.  1) Depending upon if you are using the 32-bit of 64-bit version of .Net the size of of your object will be different.  This means there is no way to have consistent behavior unless you wrote different versions of your program for the different .Net implementations.  Even then there is no guarantee of the behavior Jon observed, this is something that you should not care about. 2) The size of the object is rounded to a byte boundary. So even if there was no overhead for the object itself, the size of the object is not necessarily the sum of the parts, it may in fact be larger.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve that in the following way:

First I would make a class:

```
 class SCSI_ADDRESS
{
    public ulong Length;
    public byte PortNumber;
    public byte PathId;
    public byte TargetId;
    public byte Lun;

    public SCSI_ADDRESS(ulong Length, byte PortNumber, byte PathId, byte TargetId, byte Lun)
    {
        this.Length = Length;
        this.PortNumber = PortNumber;
        this.PathId = PathId;
        this.TargetId = TargetId;
        this.Lun = Lun;
    }

}
```

Then in the main method I would do the following.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Object[] o = new Object[256];
   SCSI_ADDRESS sa = new SCSI_ADDRESS(10, 1, 1, 1, 1); //example
   o[0] = sa;
}
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: I think OP is trying to use the [`SCSI_ADDRESS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff565299(VS.85).aspx) in the Windows Driver Kit.  This type is already defined.  I think OP really needs to learn about marshaling to native types using P/Invoke.

Comment: Well you are probably right. I that case I see no point in switching from C++ to C#.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SCSI_ADDRESS
{   
    public uint Length;     // 4 bytes, (uint in C# == ulong in C++)
    public byte PortNumber; // 1 byte
    public byte PathId;     // 1 byte
    public byte TargetId;   // 1 byte
    public byte Lun;        // 1 byte
                            // Total: 8 bytes

}

// 256 / sizeof(SCSI_ADDRESS) == 256 / 8 == 32
public SCSI_ADDRESS[] inquiry_data = new byte[256 / sizeof(SCSI_ADDRESS)];

sa = inquiry_data[0];
```